# I can't access second wan router from first router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have a local wide network around my home and area with two CPE AP.

- The main router IP address which feed from ADSL is (192.168.1.1) DHCP pool from 2 to 100
- I have a cat45 cable from first router to a switch with 16 ports connected with IP cameras, home routers and AP CPE
- All IP cameras have a static IP from 192.168.1.70 - 192.168.1.85 also NVR
- All other routers has a static ip address  from 192.168.1.101 - 192.168.1.106
- For the CPE first CPE is connected to the switch and the IP address is 192.168.1.120
- Second CPE is connected to WAN IP address 192.168.10.1 and DHCP is enabled to distribute IPs to other devices connected to the second cpe,

I can access all the devices that feed from the switch on the first router from the second router WAN, but I can't access the second CPE from the first router.

I can't see devices on the first CPE from WAN CPE

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Could please draw a network topological graphic? It will be very helpful to understand your network environment.

You didn't mention the relationship between the 192.168.1.0/24 and 192.168.10.0/24. I suspect they are not routed, they may be NATed. It may explain why you encounter the accessing issue. Any computer behind a NAT device can not be access from external directly. Unless 1to1 NAT or PAT has been configured.

If my assumption is correct. I would suggest you changing your network architecture. All subnets should be routable, so that the devices in different subnets can access each other without any issues.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello Dear David, thank you for your support and quick answer , i just drawn a diagram of my network , but i can't attach pictures in here?

Comment: @YousefNofal You may edit your original post and add the picture to it.